# A lattice generated by two particular sublattices of the lattice of binary relations

Tags: set-theory, lattice-orders, set-partition

Let $U$ be some set.

Let $\Gamma$ be the set of all finite unions $\bigcup_{X\in S}(X\times Y_X)$ where $S$ is a finite partition of $U$ and $Y_X\in\mathscr{P}U$ for every $X\in S$ (that is $Y$ is a function from $S$ to $\mathscr{P}U$).

Obviously, $\Gamma$ is a a distributive lattice.

Let $\Gamma^{-1}$ be the result of reversing x and y in every element of $\Gamma$.

What is the sublattice of the lattice of all binary relations on $U$ generated by the sublattices $\Gamma$ and $\Gamma^{-1}$?

Comment: I'm not shure, how your all quantification works. I suppose you mean all partitons and a fixed mapping $Y:\mathfrak PU\to \mathfrak PU:X\mapsto Y_X$.

Comment: @Keinstein: No, I mean all finite partitions of $U$ and every function $Y$ for a given partition. $Y$ is a mapping from $S$ into $\mathscr{P}U$ not from $\mathscr{P}U$ to $\mathscr{P}U$

Comment: Maybe, it is the lattice consisting of all finite unions of pairwise non-intersecting cartesian products?

Comment: If I understand this correctly, $\Gamma = \mathscr{P}(U \times U)$ when $U$ is finite, yes?  So the question is only interesting when $U$ is infinite.  What kind of a description would constitute an answer to this question?

Comment: @JairTaylor: Yes. Maybe the answer is the set of all finite unions of cartesian products?